# Access Ubuntu Touch 14.10 storage from PC

Tags: ubuntu-touch, storage, aquaris

To access Ubuntu Touch storage from the PC I've read that I need to act on **settings > storage**. I feel like I'm missing something stupid, but I can't *find* **storage** in my Ubuntu Touch 14.10 settings scope (BQ Aquaris 4.5)

Edit: my goal was to expose the content of the SD card via either *usb-storage* or *MTP* over USB so that application on the desktop PC can act with them. I could use some kind of internet-based rsync to `/media/user/something`, but that sounds like hunting goldfish with a harpoon!

Answer (score 1):

The MTP export works by default (no need to enter development mode) as long as the phone is unlocked.

If you have 14.04 you are probably missing the fuse rules, so to add them follow [this guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226702) (my  BQ Aquaris 4.5 UE product Id is 2a47/2008), you see it at end of dmesg after plugging in the phone.
Still working on a way to expose it as *usb-storage*

Comment: See my answer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/368221/is-the-ubuntu-phone-filesystem-mountable-via-a-usb-connection/654850#654850 for exposing the sd-card as mass-storage. It works well with Aquaris E5. Maybe, it also works with Aquaris E4.5.

Answer (score 0):

There is **Settings > About this phone > Storage** but this is just for statistics.

I think what you're looking for is External Drives from the Apps screen. I don't have an SD card though so can't be a 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks, I myself expected a configuration there, but as long as I can see (not much uncertainity actually) the only options are unmount or format

Comment: In theory the SD card should be visible to the PC without any additional settings - have you checked if it's visible while the phone screen is unlocked (and development mode activated for just in case)? Also have you tried connecting the phone to different operating systems for just in case this is a problem only with a certain OS?

Comment: You're right! The problem was a couple of missing fuse rules on my 14.04.2; on 15.04 worked out of the box in MTP mode. There is no need for the phone to be in development mode. Still working on shotwell to recognize it, but I guess if I don't find a cleaner way I can wrap it in a rsync script.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any <kbd>storage</kbd> button: Ubuntu Touch will detect files on an inserted SD card and show them in the correct scopes...

That's it!

Comment: Ok, maybe I misexplained it: I want the phone to export the sd card to the connected PC via usb-storage or similar, so that the PC application (Shotwell, Rythmbox, etc) can interact with them; the (definitely more complicated) alternative would be to connect via BT and then fake the PC kernel to expose it as usb-storage, as most user programs expect them this way. I had read [this answer] (https://support.mozilla.org/it/questions/979787), but now I realize it refers to Firefox OS

Comment: You need to put it in developer mode then...  :-)

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not require any cables and will provide you with wireless access to your phone's file system without developer mode.

You may want to consider [enabling SSH Service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348714/how-can-i-access-my-ubuntu-phone-over-ssh/601972#601972). Follows the link in the answer and then proceed with its instructions to be able to toggle the SSH Service. This is on 15.04 though.

Once you have done that you can sftp into your phones file system, rsync with it or even mount it with sshfs.

To have your SDCard appear in your home directory, simply follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/651734/unlock-sd-card-ubuntu-touch/653606#653606).