# How can I transfer photos to PC from Meizu Ubuntu phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, file-sharing, meizu-mx4

I have the Meizu Ubuntu phone and use Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. `dmesg|grep -i usb` detects the phone when connected via usb, but even in developer mode I cannot browse the files or transfer photos to my PC.

Maybe I was not clear enough. I can connect the Meizu Ubuntu phone to a MacBook Pro with Android File Transfer installed, and it works out of the box. I can see my folders in the file manager and transfer photos. I am looking for a way to do the same in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Related question with several answers: http://askubuntu.com/questions/368221/is-the-ubuntu-phone-filesystem-mountable-via-a-usb-connection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the ubuntu phone filesystem mountable via a usb connection?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368221/is-the-ubuntu-phone-filesystem-mountable-via-a-usb-connection)

Answer (score 2):

I followed [this post on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226702).
This solved the problem and I can see my device (Meizu MX4 Ubuntu Edition) in the file manager and transfer files without any problems.

> 1. Install some of the common MTP apps that will be needed. Open up a terminal and type the following two lines one after the other.
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install libmtp-common mtp-tools libmtp-dev libmtp-runtime libmtp9  
>    sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
>    ```
> 2. Amend the fuse.conf file. FUSE is an application that aims to provide a secure method for non privileged users to create and mount
>      their own file system implementations. This option overrides the
>      security measure restricting file access to the user mounting the file
>      system. So all users (including root) can access the files. This
>      option is by default only allowed to root, but this restriction can be
>      removed with a change to the aforementioned fuse.conf file as follows:
>
>    ```
>    sudo nano /etc/fuse.conf
>    ```
>
>    We want to remove the # from the below line of code for user_allow_other, like this:
>
>    ```
>    #/etc/fuse.conf - Configuration file for Filesystem in Userspace (FUSE)
>
>    #Set the maximum number of FUSE mounts allowed to non-root users.
>    #The default is 1000.
>    #mount_max = 1000
>
>    # Allow non-root users to specify the allow_other or allow_root mount options.
>    user_allow_other
>    ```
>
>    Now save the file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, type <kbd>Y</kbd> and then press<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 3. Set up some rules for our device that we plan on connecting, but before we do that we need to find out both the vendor and product id.
>
>    Connect your device via an available USB port and from terminal run:
>
>    ```
>    lsusb
>    ```
>
>    This should bring up an output similar to the following:
>
>    ```
>    Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0fce:01b1 Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB 
>    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
>    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
>    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>    Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0461:4d65 Primax Electronics, Ltd 
>    Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0846:9020 NetGear, Inc. WNA3100(v1) Wireless-N 300 [Broadcom BCM43231]
>    ```
>
>    You need to look for your device, in this instance my Sony Tablet is at the top of the list, the vendor id is 0fce and product id is
>      01b1.
> 4. Amend the mtp udev rules as follows and type:
>
>    ```
>    sudo nano /lib/udev/rules.d/69-mtp.rules
>    ```
>
>    Then add the below line of code:
>
>    ```
>    # Sony Xperia Z2 Tablet
>    ATTR{idVendor}=="0fce", ATTR{idProduct}=="01b1", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"
>    ```
>
>    Remember what you're changing here is the device name next to the `#`, this can be whatever you want, the `#` comments out the code, but for clarity and reference later I would choose the name of your
>      tablet/phone and also the vendor id and product id, they should match
>      what was seen when you issued the `lsusb` command earlier.
>
>    Once done, save the file.
> 5. Add a line of code to the 51 android rules file:
>
>    ```
>    sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
>    ```
>
>    Then add the following line of code:
>
>    ```
>    ATTR{idVendor}=="", ATTR{idProduct}=="", MODE=”0666"
>    ```
>
>    What is highlighted in red needs to be changed to your device product id and vendor id.
> 6. Once that is done and the file is saved, remove any USB device currently connected and run the following command:
>
>    ```
>    sudo service udev restart
>    ```
> 7. Save any other remaining work you may have open and reboot the system.
>
>    ```
>    sudo reboot
>    ```
>
> Once rebooted you should now be able to plug your Android device
>   in(making sure the screen is unlocked) and VIOLA!!(or at least I hope)
>   You will now be able to transfer data to/from your Android device via
>   the much quicker and much more reliable MTP