# Ubuntu 14.04 desktop not finding Ubuntu phone (Ubuntu 15.04)

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-touch, 15.04, phone, adb

I have an Ubuntu 15.04(r4) Phone, specifically a meizu MX4, connected via usb to my desktop that is running Ubuntu 14.04. My desktop has qt creator on it with the ubuntu SDK, but it can't see my phone.

It shows:

```
Detecting device.. * there is no device connected
```

In the terminal the "adb devices list" is empty, even after I've started the server.

Developer mode is active on the phone, but when I want to start the adb daemon adbd with the terminal, I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" and I don't see it running.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 14.04 can't detect bq "natively" cause of outdated libs. Maybe there is the same issue for meixu.

Add this ppa should works.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately.. 
I added the ppa on my desktop and there is still no connection.

I see the server running on mij desktop..
jorrovic  4542  0.0  0.0  96796  1608 ?        Sl   15:21   0:00 adb -P 5037 fork-server server

.. and a daemon on my phone.
root      2076  0.0  0.0   4128  1212 ?        Ss   14:14   0:00 su - -c adbd
phablet   2077  0.0  0.0  41260  1696 ?        Ssl  14:14   0:00 adbd

Comment: Hi Joris Van Boven, did you try this : http://askubuntu.com/questions/657755/meizu-ubuntu-phone-transfer-photos-to-pc

Comment: yes it worked!
After step 2, my phone get recognized by Ubuntu and i can copy files to phone.
I don't notice a difference after step 4-7 (more functionalities or something else).

Only my QT SDK is still not working.
It can see my phone, but is telling me..
"No network connection on your device[
you will need to connect your device ta a network with connection to the internet.
Then replug the device to your workstation".
But this will be beter for an othere topic, i think.

So step 1 and 2 were very useful for me!
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226702

Thanks alot!